# How can I fix my Scheme error: Argument #1 '()' to 'car' has wrong type (empty-list)

Tags: list, split, scheme, racket

Write a function that takes a list and a length as input and returns two lists: (1) The first length elements of the input list, and (2) the remainder of the input list. Hint: Use a helper method with an "accumulator" parameter. I'm stuck guys and could really use some help.

I keep getting error when I try to do (split-list '(a b c d e f g) 7) which is the number equal to length otherwise any number less than than that does what its supposed to do
:

`Argument #1 '()' to 'car' has wrong type (empty-list)`

`(split-list '(a b c d e f g) 0)` should return `'(() (a b c d e f g))`

`(split-list '(a b c d e f g) 1)` should return `'((a) (b c d e f g))`

`(split-list '(a b c d e f g) 3)` should return `'((a b c) (d e f g))`

```
(define (split-list lst length) 
    (define(split-list-head accum length)
        (if (= length 0)
            (cdr '(accum))
            (cons (car accum) (split-list-head (cdr accum)(- length 1)))
        )
    )
    
    (define(split-list-tail accum length)
        (if (= length 0)
            (cons (car accum)(cdr accum))
            (split-list-tail (cdr accum)(- length 1))
        )
    )

    (if (eq? length 0) 
        (append(list (list))(list lst))
        (append(list(split-list-head lst length)) (list(split-list-tail lst length)))
    )
)
```

Comment: Did you make and then delete another question about this assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are particularly attached to GNU Scheme, I would consider moving to Dr Racket.

Although it was written for a similar language called Racket, it can be set up to run vanilla Scheme, by putting in a first line `#lang scheme`

The nice about Dr Racket is that it has a very nice debugger.

My code, with the #lang line at the start, and the erroring line at the bottom:

```
#lang scheme

(define (split-list lst length) 
    (define(split-list-head accum length)
        (if (= length 0)
            (cdr '(accum))
            (cons (car accum) (split-list-head (cdr accum)(- length 1)))
        )
    )

    (define(split-list-tail accum length)
        (if (= length 0)
            (cons (car accum)(cdr accum))
            (split-list-tail (cdr accum)(- length 1))
        )
    )

    (if (eq? length 0) 
        (append(list (list))(list lst))
        (append(list(split-list-head lst length)) (list(split-list-tail lst length)))
    )
)

(split-list '(a b c d e f g) 7)
```

If I just run the code, it highlights the error in `split-list-tail`, where `car` causes a contract violation. It also shows the call sequence.

[image]

That's probably enough to identify the fault, but I can also run the debugger. By clicking on the Debug button I move to the debug mode. By moving the mouse pointer over a parenthesis, and right clicking, I can enable or disable a pause at this point - show by a pink circle. The variables are shown on the right hand side. When I run the code in the debugger, variable `accum` is empty, hence `car accum` fails.

[image]

My suggestion is that you use `pair?` or `null?` to test `accum` before calling `car` on it.

Comment: `#lang scheme` is not vamnilla but just a synonym for `#lang racket`. You'll need to use one of the report languages to get Scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It makes use of three accumulating parameters. A subtraction is also kind of accumulation.

```
(define (split n xs k)
  (define (loop xs n k)
    (if
      (and (> n 0) (not (null? xs)))
      (loop (cdr xs) (- n 1) 
             (lambda (a b) (k (cons (car xs) a) b)))
      (k '() xs)))
  (loop xs n k))
```

Can you see how it is to be called?

Can you explain how it works?

Or a bit shorter,

```
(define (split n xs k)
  (define ((+ f a) b) (f (cons (car a) b)))
  (define (loop xs n k)
    (if
      (and (> n 0) (not (null? xs)))
      (loop (cdr xs) (- n 1) (+ k xs))
      ((k '()) xs)))
  (loop xs n k))
```

Can you find a way how should *this* function be called? I'll give you a hint, how should this function

```
(define ((add a) b) (list a b))
```

be called?